# validation of AngularJS direcrives

Tags: html, angularjs, validation

I read on W3C School that to make a valid HTML page I have to add `data` before each angular directive in HTML file (e.g.:

```
<p>The name is <span data-ng-bind="firstName"></span></p>
```

or

```
<div data-ng-app="" data-ng-init="firstName='John'">
```

Ok that's fine. I have two questions:

1. Should this prefix be used only for `ng-` directives?
2. Could this `data-` prefix create problems with Angular third-party libraries?

Comment: Did you mean w3schools? If so it is not related to W3C.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`data-` prefix can be used by any directive and the underlying directive name normalization process takes care of matching the directive attribute declaration with the directive implementation.

More details about the normalization process is available in the [directive user guide](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive) under section "Matching Directives".

Hence adding `data-` prefix to to any directive does not affect any third party directives.

Answer (score 0):

As of recent, `data` is not commonly used as a prefix as most users of angular simply use `ng-` instead. Using `data` may give you some added backwards compatibility, but nothing significant, seeing as most people do not use it anymore. It is not incorrect to use the `data` prefix, it is simply unnecessary.

Comment: OK, but when i validate HTML code with W3C-validator https://validator.w3.org/nu/, it rise some errors without data. Perhaps, as you suggested, because of backwards compatibility?

Comment: I would think yes. But anyway, feel free to use `data-ng-` unless there exists another validator that does not require this.